Is there a principle in the “always”?
When I was a child, one of the questions I asked my grandmother the most was, “Is there a year 0”? Yes, at that time, for a 4 year old human being it was a big thing if there was a year with such a digit. I still didn't understand very well how the numbers of the years worked. Later I discovered that indeed, in fact it is the year of the point before and after Christ.
And speaking of theology, God is related to the infinite, that is, he exists since forever. I believe in him, but even so there are things in his "origin" that cause me to speculate.
Because then... what is He always? How would things be defined finitus or not? I recently did a paper on time, and there I debated whether or not it possessed a clear end. Of course, the time of things has an expiration date, but what about time itself? The numbers are infinite, or so they say, because it is only necessary to keep adding digits to the numbers in continuation.
And also, I used to think that they meant only the numbers to the right of zero, so that “infinity” had a beginning. i used to have no idea that negatives existed. So, what do you say? now they are infinite on both sides! And, they really don't have a limit? Just like the universe and all that?
Because I think the usual thing is that everything has a beginning, right? And some supposedly determined end.

Hi and welcome. It's always refreshing to hear a 16 year old grapple with philosophy. From the pov of this site you need to clarify whether this question is about religion/theology/etc or about math. Note: counting from zero rather than one is common and natural in comp. science. See

As to the theology I'll leave it to persons more steeped in Christian doctrine than I. Some broad philosophy advice: There are two key concepts to grok — necessary and contingent. We humans straddle these two worlds. When we understand something deeply there is invariably something necessary. However our human existence is contingent. Eg Just now you're 16. 17 years ago you were non existent. So your existence is contingent on the time point. For a beginner Plato is always a good start to delve deeper into philosophy.

Maybe we're  contingent beings (really creatures) whereas God is a necessary being? Just something to think on. BTW for a Christian God is a necessary being. For a Hindu, God is necessary being. Do you grok the difference?

Welcome to the site, Fer! Some useful links if you need them: the tour, how to ask, and what topics are on-topic. I also want to recommend our sister sites Christianity StackExchange (supposing you're Christian--there's similar sites for Judaism, Islam, Hinduism, Buddhism, etc.) and Math StackExchange, both of which I'm sure have questions about infinity/eternity.

I submitted an edit to the post that does a few things: 1. Removes your intro/outro paragraphs. It's silly, but StackExchange started as a programming help site so the idea is that each question should "stand alone" as just the question. (see here). (That said, you could absolutely edit your profile and tell us about yourself if you'd like. 2. Just some edits for grammar and clarity. 3. I suggested some tags that might be more relevant.

You should be able to check the changes in the edit and revert anything if you'd like (or revert it all the way if you want). If you can, there's two things you might [edit] the question to clarify: 1. "defined finitus or not"--I wasn't sure how to clarify this, so I left it as-is. Do you mean 'finite' (having an end), 'finished' (having reached the end)? 2. If you had to boil down the question to a single sentence, what would it be? (It's fine if you have multiple questions, but it might be better to focus this on one of them, and then ask another question!)

Again, welcome to the site! I know it's a lot to get used to, but we're here to help. If you need help, you can ask in a chatroom or on the meta-site!

I don't think there is any reason why time shouldn't be infinite in both ways. It is the more elegant assumption because it also avoids the question: where does this all come from? Who or what created the universe? With the time dimension stretching into infinity in both directions, there is no need for these questions.

Obvious — if time is an underlying ontic for the empirical world — ­a very classical view. If time itself is a 'resultant' of matter (can follow from relativity or from Kant among others) then its not at all obvious

@Rushi If.... .

The issue is not with time itself, bit with the narrative and mechanics of a universe that has always existed.

In Christian doctrine, God is prior to all things, even time or space.
To explain this idea, which ironically uses time-based wording ("prior"), Christian mystics need to explain this idea in many ways that are very paradoxical at first glance, and that's probably just because time and space are so baked-in to our language.
Some explanations include:

God is everywhere
God is outside of space
God exists at all points in time
God exists outside of time
God is infinite

Contradictions which explain abound in religious movements, like Zen koans
